# Java Enumeration with values()

Tags: java

Good night guys,

I wanted to ask, why it's not possible, to print out the content of an enumeration without a for loop.

For example this:

```
public class NurTests {

    enum optionen{
       Option1, Option2, Option3;
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (optionen d: optionen.values()){
        System.out.println(d);
    }
  }
}
```

Why can't I write this? Or why can't I write System.out.println(optionen) either?

```
System.out.println(optionen.values());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(optionen.values()));`

Comment: So when I write System.out.println(optionen); the compiler (IntelliJ) tells me that it's not an expression. And if I write System.out.println(optionen.values()) it prints [LNurTests$optionen;@7852e922. If I do it with the for loop it works.

Comment: Becuase for an enum, `values()` returns an array, not a `String`